# How to list what command listed inside os.system() in python?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am trying to list command under  os.system() 
using help("modules os.system") but not getting any output.

help("modules os.system")

Comment: the module is `os`, `os.system` is a function in `os`.

Comment: Welcome to SO @rupesh, os.system() takes the parameter as the system command on which you are running python... So all your system commands are your required list...if you are on Linux you can write os.system("ls /usr/bin")...In windows os.system("help")...

Comment: use `help(os.system)` but `os.system()` is function, not module, so you can get information about parameters.

Comment: There _is no_ "command under `os.system()`", so you are asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built-in method `dir`

```
dir(os.system)
```